# Line integral across perfect dipole

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields, calculus, dipole

In problem 4.7 of Griffiths' "*Introduction to electrodynamics, 4th Edition*", we are asked to find the potential energy of a dipole in an electric field, $\vec{E}$. In the solution, the following step is made in the limit that the dipole is perfect:

> $$\lim_{\vec{d}\to 0} \,\, \int_{\vec{r}}^{\vec{r}+\vec{d}} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{x} = \vec{E} \cdot \vec{d}$$

I understand intuitively why this is the case, however are there some slightly more formal intermediate steps for this reasoning (I'm imagining something along the lines of a first order Taylor expansion or similar)? Also, does this step assume the field is uniform?

Edit:
The last line in the image below is the step I am referring to.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure which solution are you looking at, but the easy way I know for computing the energy of a point dipole sitting, say, at the origin, is by performing a Taylor expansion of the potential in $W = \int \rho(\mathbf{x}) \Phi(\mathbf{x}) \ d^3x = 
\int \rho(\mathbf{x}) \left[\Phi(\mathbf{0})
+ \mathbf{x} \cdot \nabla \Phi(\mathbf{0}) \ + \ ... \right] d^3x = q \ \Phi(\mathbf{0}) - \int \rho(\mathbf{x}) \ \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{0}) \ d^3x \ + \ ... = q \ \Phi(\mathbf{0}) - \mathbf{p}  \cdot \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{0}) \ + \ ...$

Comment: @secavara see the edit for the solution I am looking at. In your derivation, is the expression you give the potential energy of the orientation (rotation) of the dipole?

Comment: I am not sure how to interpret the computation in the edit given the book's question, i.e. the energy of a point dipole in the presence of an external field: $W$. I integrate over the charge distribution of interest ($\rho$, in this case, the one of the dipole) and the potential of the external field ($\Phi$). I then expand $\Phi$ around the position of the dipole (notice that we don't know anything specific about the external field, except for the fact that whatever sources generate it do not include the dipole and live somewhere else). In my expression $q=0$, the total charge of the dipole.